# ¿Cómo soluciono el error required: int[], int, int found: int[]?

Tags: java, ordenamiento, packages, quicksort

Buen día a todos. Estoy efectuando un proyecto dentro de Java con las siguientes clases: **quickSort.java**, **Tools.java** y una clase principal denominada como: **Main.java**. Cada clase en un archivo distinto y con la función de package: package SortAlgorithm.

Para emplearlas en la clase Main.java (la cual contiene el método principal necesario.

Mi problema, es que una vez establecida mi clase Main.java, esta no compila y ni ejecuta.

Arrojando el siguiente error:
**required: int[],int,int
found: int[]**

¿Serían tan amables de ayudarme a solucionarlo? Por favor.
Aquí están los códigos de dichas clases, si son necesarias.

```
// Código de mi clase Main.java.
package SortAlgorithm;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]){  
        
            int[] array = {1, 6, 83, 85, 322, 36, 433, 6};
            
            System.out.println("array sin ser ordenado:");  
            Tools.printArray(array);
       
            
            Quicksort.QuickSort(array, 0, arr.length-1);
            
            System.out.println("arreglo ya ordenado:");
            Utilerias.printArray(array);
    }
}

// Código de mi clase Tools.java.
package SortAlgorithm;

public class Tools {
    
    public static void printArray(int array[]){
        int n = array.length;
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
            System.out.print(array[i]+" ");
        System.out.println();
 }
    
    public static void swap(int array[], int i, int j){
        int temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
}

// Código de mi clase quickSort.java.
package SortAlgorithm;

public class quickSort {
   public static int partition(int array[], int low, int high){
        int pivot = array[high];
        int i = (low-1);
        for (int j=low; j<high; j++){
            if (array[j] <= pivot)
            {
                i++;
                Utilerias.swap(array, i, j);
            }
        }
        
        int temp = array[i+1];
        arr[i+1] = array[high];
        arr[high] = temp;
        return i+1;
    }
    
    public static void QuickSort(int array[], int low, int high){
        if (low < high){
            int pi = partition(array, low, high);
            QuickSort(array, low, pi-1);
            QuickSort(array, pi+1, high);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ayudaría si dijeras el error completo.

Comment: El código tiene un montón de errores de "typos", variables que no existen, unas veces llamas a algo utilidades y otras veces lo llamas tools, en fin. Lo corregí y acá te lo dejo https://onlinegdb.com/YuC9TTefD. Puedes ejecutar el programa online.